# EF code first many-to-many with shortcut

Tags: .net, ef-code-first

I'm trying to set up a many-to-many relationship with a shortcut on one side of the relationship. It'll be easier to explain with some code:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> Details { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I'd like to have my order details on the order side. But, on the product side, I'd like to only have the linked orders. EF generates the wrong database schema as it adds a Producty_Id FK on the Orders table.

I tried to give specific model creating instruction without success like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(x => x.Orders);
}
```

Thanks for any help!
Fabian

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to have my order details on the order side. But, on the
>   product side, I'd like to only have the linked orders. EF generates
>   the wrong database schema as it adds a Producty_Id FK on the Orders
>   table.

This is not possible with EF. You may make it an unmapped property and manually implement the logic inside the property. But it would be a leaky abstraction.

Proper way would be to map `OrderDetail` collection property to `Product` entity.

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is how I do it now. Note that the property on the Product side will be read only.

Comment: @FabianVilers you need to have public getters and setters for properties for mapped properties. If you need finer control over your model try NHibernate.

Comment: Thx, I'll have a look at NHibernhate.